# Issue in creating correct XML in C#

Tags: c#, xml, xml-serialization

I am facing an issue in generating an XML in REST web service. A root element is getting created for array type of elements. I want a flat structure of Array element and the root node must not come in the output.

The XML need to be created is

```
<RootOrderStatus xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <Envelope>
        <FunctionalAcknowledgment i:nil="true" />
        <Header>
            <Currency>US</Currency>
            <Language>En-U</Language>
            <Vendor i:nil="true" />
        </Header>
    </Envelope>
<Envelope>
        <FunctionalAcknowledgment i:nil="true" />
        <Header>
            <Currency>US</Currency>
            <Language>En-U</Language>
            <Vendor i:nil="true" />
        </Header>
    </Envelope>
```

The XML getting generated is

```
<RootOrderStatus xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<Envelope>
    <RootOrderStatusEnvelope>
        <FunctionalAcknowledgment i:nil="true" />
        <Header>
            <Currency>US</Currency>
            <Language>En-U</Language>
            <Vendor i:nil="true" />
        </Header>
    </RootOrderStatusEnvelope>
<RootOrderStatusEnvelope>
        <FunctionalAcknowledgment i:nil="true" />
        <Header>
            <Currency>US</Currency>
            <Language>En-U</Language>
            <Vendor i:nil="true" />
        </Header>
    </RootOrderStatusEnvelope>
</Envelope>
```

The class object structure is

```
  /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true)]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute(Namespace = "", IsNullable = false)]
    public partial class RootOrderStatus
    {

        private RootOrderStatusEnvelope[] envelopeField;

        /// <remarks/>
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("Envelope")]
        public RootOrderStatusEnvelope[] Envelope
        {
            get
            {
                return this.envelopeField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.envelopeField = value;
            }
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true)]
    public partial class RootOrderStatusEnvelope
    {

        private object functionalAcknowledgmentField;

        private RootOrderStatusEnvelopeHeader headerField;

        /// <remarks/>
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(IsNullable = true)]
        public object FunctionalAcknowledgment
        {
            get
            {
                return this.functionalAcknowledgmentField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.functionalAcknowledgmentField = value;
            }
        }

        /// <remarks/>
        public RootOrderStatusEnvelopeHeader Header
        {
            get
            {
                return this.headerField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.headerField = value;
            }
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true)]
    public partial class RootOrderStatusEnvelopeHeader
    {

        private string currencyField;

        private string languageField;

        private object vendorField;

        /// <remarks/>
        public string Currency
        {
            get
            {
                return this.currencyField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.currencyField = value;
            }
        }

        /// <remarks/>
        public string Language
        {
            get
            {
                return this.languageField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.languageField = value;
            }
        }

        /// <remarks/>
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(IsNullable = true)]
        public object Vendor
        {
            get
            {
                return this.vendorField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.vendorField = value;
            }
        }
    }
```

The class object structure is created by using the PASTE XML as CLASS feature of Visual studio.

Comment: You need a class for each level of the xml.  So you need a new class Envelope and put RootOrderStatusEnvelope in the Envelope Class.

Answer (score 0):

First of all: The XML you posted is missing the closing tag `</RootOrderStatus>` at the end. After adding that tag, you might get better results with the Paste As XML function.

Secondly, another option you could try is using the generated C# code from this site: http://xmltocsharp.azurewebsites.net/